# How is the maximum volume size supported by the F2FS file system determined?

Tags: filesystems, f2fs

The maximum volume size supported by the f2fs file system 16TiB.
How is this value determined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage device is divided into blocks of size 4096 bytes. The block addresses are 32 bits in size, which results in a maximum size of 2^32 * 4096 bytes = 16 TB. This information was taken from [this Lwn.net article](https://lwn.net/Articles/518988/) from the year 2012.